# How to set Z-index of calender control in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Here i am stuck in wpf calender control.I am using a calender control in WPF but when i call it on `GotFocus` event of `TextBox` like

```
private void txtjobdate_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            calendar1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
```

It always show behind the other controls like
[image]

**xaml code**

```xml
<Window x:Class="PhotoSaver.PhotoGraphyJob_Management.AddEditPhotoGraphyJob"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="AddEditPhotoGraphyJob" Height="387" Width="511" xmlns:dxlc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/layoutcontrol" xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors">
    <Grid>
        <GroupBox>
            <GroupBox.Header>
                <Label>PhotoGraphy Job</Label>
            </GroupBox.Header>
            <Calendar Height="170"  Name="calendar1" Width="180" Visibility="Hidden" SelectedDatesChanged="calendar1_SelectedDatesChanged" AllowDrop="True" />
        </GroupBox>
        <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Job Name" Margin="92,39,149,0" Name="JobName" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" LabelPosition="Left" LabelHorizontalAlignment="Center" LabelVerticalAlignment="Center" ElementSpace="5" >
            <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtjobname" />
        </dxlc:LayoutItem>
        <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Job Date" Margin="96,78,149,0" Name="JobDate" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" LabelPosition="Left" LabelHorizontalAlignment="Center" LabelVerticalAlignment="Center" ElementSpace="5" >
            <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtjobdate" DataContext="{Binding}" GotFocus="txtjobdate_GotFocus" />
        </dxlc:LayoutItem>

        <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="Image Folder" Margin="75,117,149,0" Name="ImageFolder" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" LabelPosition="Left" LabelHorizontalAlignment="Center" LabelVerticalAlignment="Center" ElementSpace="5" >
            <dxe:TextEdit Name="txtimagefolder" />
        </dxlc:LayoutItem>
        <Button Content="Browse" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="356,114,0,0" Name="Browse" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Browse_Click" />
        <Button Content="Update" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="151,181,0,0" Name="Update" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Panel.ZIndex="1" />
        <Button Content="Clear" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="265,181,0,0" Name="Clear" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Please guide me that how i can solve this problem by showing calender control above the other controls.

Hope you all understand my question and guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Right click the calendar object --> Order --> Bring to front.

2) Alternatively, just move the GroupBox item to the bottom of the declarations inside the 
   `<Grid>` (z-order is bottom (highest) to top (lowest)).  Perhaps a bit counterintuitive.

Comment: @Rahul - yes, I should have thought of that.  The calendar is in a groupbox so "Bring to Front" just brings it to the front of the groupbox, not to the front of the other controls.  Bring to front would work (right-click) if you did it on the GroupBox, however.