# Close image in wpf after showing

Tags: c#, wpf, image, button

I've made a simple button - and when you press it an image will appear.
I've made the `image.Stretch = "Fill"` so my problem now is:

When the image appears, how do I get back? how to I close the image again, without stopping the program.

My code under the button_click is simple:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   nr1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

I want somehow to make the image hidden again..

Here is my xaml code

```
<Button Name="Button1" Content="1" Click="Button_Click" />

<Image Name="nr1" Visibility="Hidden" Source="(ImageSource etc.)" "      Stretch="Fill"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your xaml?

Comment: What is the criteria to remove image? After some time?

Comment: it really doesn't matter. Time, click - anything that'll do!

Comment: How about using **another button** (to hide `nr1`)? Or using `ToggleButton` instead of `Button` (similar to Mohit Shrivastava's answer)?

Comment: @Sinatr Yeah i tried that. But the problem is, that the image is "Stretch="Fill" , so you can't see anything else than the image - the image is filling the whole program :-)!

Comment: You have to define button **after** image in xaml. This is called z-order. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17084359/1997232) (similar to your issue).

Comment: I think you are using Grid as a container of both Button and Image. The second time you click, the button is no longer hittable.

Comment: Isn't there an event that closes the image when you click on it? :-)

Comment: Yes, there is, you can attach event handler to image `MouseDown` event and hide image there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Name="Button1" Content="1" Click="Button1_OnClick"/>
    <Button Name="nr1"  Visibility="Hidden" Click="Nr1_OnClick">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image  Source="YourImage" Stretch="Fill" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</Grid>


private void Button1_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (nr1.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            nr1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            Button1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {

            nr1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Button1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }

    private void Nr1_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Button1.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            Button1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            nr1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            nr1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            Button1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```

I believe this is similar to Sinatr's suggestion.
I hope you get the idea.